# How to use a CustomScoreQuery in Lucene 7.x

Tags: java, lucene

I'm relativly new to Lucene and want to implement my own CustomScoreQuery since I need it for my University.

I used the Lucene demo as my starting point to index all documents in a Folder and want to score them using my own algorithm.

Here are the links to the source code of the demo.

https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html
https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html

I'm checking with Luke: Lucene Toolbox Project to see my Index which is as expected. My problem occurs accessing it.

```
package CustomModul;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReaderContext;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Terms;
import org.apache.lucene.queries.CustomScoreProvider;
import org.apache.lucene.queries.CustomScoreQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;

public class CountingQuery extends CustomScoreQuery {

public CountingQuery(Query subQuery) {
    super(subQuery);
}


public class CountingQueryScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {

    String _field;

    public CountingQueryScoreProvider(String field, LeafReaderContext context) {
        super(context);
        _field = field;
    }

    public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScores[]) throws IOException {           
        IndexReader r = context.reader();

        //getTermVector returns Null
        Terms vec = r.getTermVector(doc, _field);

        //*TO-DO* Algorithm

        return (float)(1.0f);       
    }   
}

protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(
        LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
    return new CountingQueryScoreProvider("contents", context);
}

}
```

In my customScore function I access the Index like described in most Tutorials. I should get access to the Index using getTermVector but it returns NULL. 
In other posts I read that this could be caused by contents being a TextField which is declared in the Lucene Demo IndexFiles.

After trying a lot of different approaches I came to the conclusion that I need help and here I am.

My Question now is if I need to adjust the Index Process (how?) or is there another way to access the Index in the ScoreProvider other then getTermVector?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the Problem myself and wanted to share my solution if someone finds this Question looking for answers.

The Problem was indeed caused by the contents being a TextField in
https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html

To solve this Problem one has to construct his own Field which I did replacing line 193 in said IndexFile with

```
FieldType myFieldType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
myFieldType.setOmitNorms(true);
myFieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS);
myFieldType.setStored(false);
myFieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);  
myFieldType.setTokenized(true);
myFieldType.freeze();
Field myField = new Field("contents",
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, 
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),
                myFieldType);
doc.add(myField);
```

this allows the use of getTermVector in the customScore Function. Hope this will help someone in the future.